# Jersey application - Error on start up

Tags: java, spring, jersey, multipartform-data

I have a Jersey application for fileupload. And during the startup or when I upload a file in my application, I get below errors in WebSphere trace logs.

**Error:**

```
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General

[7/12/16 13:26:16:263 CEST] 0000034e ContainerResp E   Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
                                 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy553, and Java type interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.

        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:284)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
```

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.app.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am not sure what was the problem here? Please help.

**Edit: 1**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public HttpServletResponse attachDocument(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                                          @Context HttpServletResponse response,
                                          @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                                          @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition filedata) {

    String webServiceResponse = //call webservice here to store document
    objectMapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), webServiceResponse);
}
```

Comment: What is the resource method the exception is thrown at?

Comment: Can you provide the Java code where your request hit ?

Comment: @jan.supol added java class.

Comment: @Iqbalhossain added

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to return `HttpServletResponse` from a jaxrs resource method. In this case, that's what the error log says:

> A message body writer for Java class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy553, and Java type interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

The interface `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` (injected by `@Context`) is implemented by proxy class `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy553`. In jersey, there is no `MessageBodyWriter` for it (unless you add one, which is not what you want to do).

There is bunch of `MessageBodyWriters` in jersey by default, mainly those named in [jaxrs specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-1.1-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/), section 4.2.4. You probably wanted to return `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`, such as:

```
return Response.ok(entity).build();
```